# Reverse order of email thread folding in Evolution

Tags: email, evolution

By default Evolution groups emails by thread in a tree-like structure. The first email is the root, the responses to it are its children, etc.

Here is a screenshot from wikipedia:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Evolution_36_mail.png

I find it more comfortable to have the emails in a thread sorted by date with the newest one being the first. In the example screenshot this will mean reversing the order of the messages. I have seen this in other mail clients. Is there a way to do this in Evolution?

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but I've just figured this out myself and could not find any information on this in Evolution's documentation.

In order to have the emails in a thread sorted by date (descending) you can set the sort order of the mail list view to date (descending) and run the following command.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.evolution.mail thread-children-ascending false
```

This setting will sort thread children using the same sort order as configured for the thread root level instead of always sorting them ascending.

From the gsettings description:

```
$ gsettings describe org.gnome.evolution.mail thread-children-ascending
This setting specifies whether the thread children should be sorted always ascending, rather 
than using the same sort order as in the thread root level.
```